# Jenkins & Bitbucket: Build on link

Tags: jenkins, build-automation, bitbucket

I'm trying to bring up the bitbucket -> jenkins link. But i've no change, tried it in different settings (see on the pictures)

it works if i call

```
http://URL/jenkins/job/PROJECTNAME/build?token=buildfromjenkins
```

May you know wheres the problem?

Jenkins Config (working)
[image: Jenkins config]
Configured Link
[image: Configured Link]

Configured a Service
[image: Configured Service]

Comment: I did not mean to post as an answer. What did you say you did to get it working?

Comment: As a workaround we use the "poll SCM" option ( it polls the bitbucket server every 5 mins and starts a build when detects a change)

Answer (score 1):

Do not add token parameter in the endpoint. Remove the parameters in the endpoint URL and add your token in Token box. Then It will work.

[image]

Comment: This options are now under Settings > Hooks, of the repository. `Module name` according to the documentation https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Jenkins+hook+management "If set, only commits to the specified module (or directory) will trigger a Jenkins build.", in my case I left `Module name` blank and now is working.